# PyGObject: How to detect the end of a Gio.DataInputStream?

Tags: python-3.x, stream, pygobject

I'm building a GTK-3 application in Python (3.6 to be precise) which launches an external binary in a `Gio.Subprocess` and reads that's output from a `Gio.DataInputStream`. I'm following this [recipe](https://fhackts.wordpress.com/2018/11/28/getting-a-subprocess-output-asynchronously-with-gio-glib-in-python/) to read the output line by line by asynchronous operations. This happens in a loop of `queue_read()` and the `_on_data()` callback, which is interrupted only by `self.cancellable` triggered from `_on_finished()` or an eventual exception during reading from the stream.

Depending on the parameters used to call the external process, there is some arbitrary delay between each line of the output (each line is a unit of measured values, which should be displayed as soon as it is available). It also can happen that my spawned process terminates way before everything is read from the stream. Therefor, I cannot cancel reading in `_on_finished()` as in the linked code - I need to read until I get the stream's end-of-file and then omit to schedule reading another line.

How can I test for `eof` on a `Gio.DataInputStream`?

In C++ io streams for example there's a flag indicating this condition. The `Gio.DataInputStream` also raises `GLib.Error` in certain situations. But neither some flag seems to be available here nor an error is raised in this case. The only condition I experienced is that the async read operation (the `_on_data()` callback) completes immediately with `line` set to `None` after the subprocess terminated and no more data is available from the stream. If this is the way to go, is it documented somewhere?

Comment: I'm afraid that without some code to have a look at, it's quite difficult to comment, first question is, do you have to use subprocess? can't you use read_all_async?

Comment: @gianmt I edited my question, which hopefully answers yours now. The code you can find behind the link in the question (1st paragraph). For the async reading procedure itself I didn't do anything special in my specific code, so I found it not appropriate to just c&p it here. I hope the references to that code I put in the question help to understand better what I mean :)